# R Working Directory "cannot change"

Tags: r

[Working Direcotry Cannot Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1nkm.png) It's saying that there's an error in my code but I've tried it multiple times with countless variations on the code (I wiped my past attempts sorry) and it refuses to change the working directory. It won't change to other things either so it's not just this folder. What's the issue?

Comment: remove the `~` and it should work.

Comment: At least on my machine, "~" points to the "My Documents" folder,  which does not contain my Desktop. Instead, try `setwd("~/../Desktop/r-novice-inflammation")`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dIAxVXc didn't work

Comment: I cannot see your image.  Could you please paste the text into your comment or question?

Comment: basically the exact same as the text in the initial issue

Comment: "Error in setwd("~/../Desktop/r-novice-inflammation") : 
  cannot change working directory" & "Error in setwd("/Desktop/r-novice-inflammation/") : 
  cannot change working directory"

Comment: Does this also throw an error? `setwd("~/../Desktop/)`

Answer (score 0):

This probably means that the directory you want to change to does not exist. From the image I think you are using Windows, in which case the proper path to the directory would look like this:

```
setwd("C:/Users/$USER$/Desktop/r-novice-inflammation"
```

Change the $USER$ to your own username and it should work.

Paths always start with the letter of the hard drive in Windows. The easiest way to find the proper path to a directory is, in my opinion, to right click on the folder and look for the "Location" in properties. The IDE RStudio has a menu which you can use to change the working directory, which may be easier than using vanilla R.

The exception is `setwd("~")` which links to the Documents folder of your current user (i.e. `C:/Users/$USER$/Documents`). Based on the comments I realised that other commands such as `setwd("..")` (i.e. one folder up in the hierarchy) can be combined with `~` which explains what you are doing. In this case the following works for me:

```
setwd("~/../Desktop/")
```

Comment: I went to go try that and then realised (being the eejit I am) that because this was a copy it had a "1" at the end I had been omitting and that solved the problem. Sorry to waste everyone's time, it took me >30 mins to figure that out